# Node.js error handling guarantee with net.createConnection

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I was wondering if Node.js provides any guarantee that the error handler will catch all errors in code like the following:

```
var c = net.createConnection(port, host);
c.on('error', function (e) { ... });
```

I've had to deal with code where other statements intervened between the call to `createConnection` and the statement which sets the error handler, and this sometimes caused errors internal to `createConnection` to percolate to the top level (presumably because these errors sometimes occurred before the error handler had been set). But unless I'm missing something, this could in principle happen in the code above -- it's just not very likely. Is there any way of actually guaranteeing that all errors which occur within `createConnection` will get passed to the error handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will only happen if there are bugs in node.

JavaScript is single threaded, the process will not normally be interrupted between attaching the event handler and creating the connection.

No error generated in javascript land will be uncaught by that code.

So if there was a bug in node, there could probably be some errors your code would not catch. If you had some dodgy low level code running in the background causing mayhem it could be possible that some errors would occur that your code would not catch.

But under normal usage, your code is "threadsafe". Your binding the event handler before any errors occur because your code is blocking and nothing can throw errors.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't match my experience. As I said, if you leave a large gap between the call to `createConnection` and the setting of the error handler, then you can get an error percolating to the top level. (I.e., `createConnection` appears not to be synchronous, and it can raise errors.)

Comment: @foldl you shouldn't leave a gap. The error handler should be on the next line from creating the connection

Comment: Yes, I understand that. However, putting it on the next line only makes it less likely that the problem will occur. Unless node provides some guarantee which I'm not aware of.

Comment: @foldl your error occurs because one of the lines _in between_ creates the error.

Comment: But `createConnection` *can* raise errors. If you attempt to create a conneciton to a non-existent host, then attach an error handler right afterwards, the error handler will get called with an error. Sorry, I'm just having difficulty seeing what guarantees that `createConnection` doesn't raise the error before the error handler is set. If the intervening code is just a loop which takes up a reasonable amount of time, the error percolates to the top level.

Comment: E.g., the following code triggers an error at the top level: http://pastebin.com/0AxbjqTZ

Comment: @foldl you have a good point, I'm wondering whether attaching the error handling immediatly makes the problem go away

Comment: Oops, actually, it's not true that the code I posted raises an error at the toplevel (not even if I make the loop last a few seconds). So it does seem that attaching the error handler immediately somehow stops this happening. I just don't yet understand *why* this works reliably. Thanks for your comments by the way, @Raynos.

Comment: @foldl :( I'll undelete my answer. My understanding is simply that JS is single threaded. So it cant get interrupted, so nothing async can happen so no async errors can throw before you bound your error handler

Comment: I see. I'd assumed (incorrectly, I guess) that an asynchronous call could put the current execution context on hold and switch to a callback (this would still be single-threaded in one sense, since you wouldn't have two different contexts executing at the same time). But as you say, it seems that node actually doesn't allow any asynch stuff to execute until the current context has stopped executing altogether. That makes sense.